# Change text on button when hover then copies a text into clipboard when click and the text will change to something and goes back

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code

```css
.btn-transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-transparent:hover {
  transition: 250ms;
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
}

#ip {
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#ip::before {
  content: "I AM REALLY COOL 123123";
}

.btn-transparent:hover #ip::before {
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
  content: "";
}

.btn-transparent:hover #ip::after {
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
  content: "Click to copy!";
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="btn-transparent" onClick="navigator.clipboard.writeText('mc.craftanvil.net');">
  <span id="ip"></span>
</div>
```

This is working fine at the moment except for a few issues...

1. The size of the button changes on hover. (That's when the text changes from "I AM REALLY COOL 123123" to "Click to copy!")
2. I have no idea how to change content of a span in js since I never touch it. And I don't know how to listen for when ever the user's cursor leaves the button so I can change the content back.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's all of my code. I will edit the code to make the button black so others can see, thanks!